# Why does P(A | B) x P( B) = P(A ∩ B), but P(B|A) x P(A) != P(A ∩ B)?

Tags: probability

I’d assume it’d be equal cause intersection is a commutative property so I assumed order didn’t matter because it’s probability of A depending on B and B depending on A so in my head that means we’re looking for the probability of the intersection regardless of order?

Comment: You edited your question after all the answers, to now ask why a *correct* statement is incorrect. Reverting the changes, since (i) it invalidates all answers that were correct at the time, and (ii) the question after the edit does not really make sense anymore (*"why is something true false?"*).

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. There was no malicious intent I assure you. It's reasonable to assume the mistake was unintentional because it was one character. All the responses regardless are very helpful and definitely made me think more. I was told by a prof they're not equal and I wasn't entirely convinced so I posted.

Comment: Well... the answer is, "the person who said that to you was wrong." Now, maybe instead of editing the title (which removes the meaning of all the answers), just edit the body of the text to add this edited statement and explain what you just wrote in a comment? That way, answers are not invalidated, and things make sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) says

\begin{equation}
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}.
\end{equation}

The LHS of your second expression is missing a $P(B)$ in the denominator.

Comment: What’s the proof for that?

Comment: @DylanYung: See the linked Wikipedia article, in particular the [Derivation section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Derivation).

Answer (score 1):

If we relabel $A,\,B$ respectively as $B,\,A$ in $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$, we get $P(B|A)P(A)=P(B\cap A)=P(A\cap B)$, not $P(A|B)$.

Answer (score 0):

By the law of conditional probability
$$P(A|B)P(B) = P(AB) = P(B|A)P(A).$$

Also, $P(AB) = P(BA)$; however, $P(A|B) \neq P(B|A)$.